# Using VBA to control a field through the conditional state of checkboxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using Access and want control over a varying amount of checkboxes. I have a main form `[Purchase_Orders]` which has a `Purchase_Order_State` field. This can be Delivered, Part delivered, or Undelivered. 
The datasheet sub form of `[PO_Parts]` has a checkbox field of `Delivery_status` for each Part of matching PO_ID.
I want to be able to control the `Purchase_order_state` in the main form based on whether none, all or some `delivery_status` checkboxes are checked.

I'm not sure where how to go about controlling this in VBA, any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a query to determine how many Parts have the matching `PO_ID` and how many of them are checked.

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim DB As Database
Dim RS As Recordset
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT Count(*) AS countAllParts, Abs(Sum(CInt(Delivery_Status))) AS countCheckedParts " _
    & "FROM yourTable " _
    & "WHERE PO_ID = " & Me.Parent.[PO_ID]

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set RS = DB.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset)

RS.MoveFirst
If RS!countCheckedParts = 0 Then
    Me.Parent.Purchase_Order_State = "Undelivered"
ElseIf RS!countAllParts = RS!countCheckedParts Then
    Me.Parent.Purchase_Order_State = "Delivered"
Else
    Me.Parent.Purchase_Order_State = "Part delivered"
End If

End Sub
```